# Swift: access UIView children from [Int: UIView]()

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I use below code for add `view` to `scrollview` and save `view` to `viewAll`

```
var viewAll = [Int: UIView]()

i = 0
for pack in packs as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
    let packId = Int(pack["packId"] as! String)
    let packTitle = pack["packTitle"] as! String

    let view = CategoryClass.createMyClassView()
    view.pcId.text = packId
    view.pcTitle.text = packTitle

    viewAll[i] = view
    i = i+1

    myScrollView.addSubview(view)
}
```

It work fine.

Now i want access again to children of view :

```
for view in viewAll {
    view.value.pcId.text = "TEST"  
}
```

This line not work : `view.value.pcId.text = "TEST"`

CategoryClass:

```
class CategoryClass: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var pcId: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pcTitle: UILabel!

    class func createMyClassView() -> CategoryClass {
        let myClassNib = UINib(nibName: "Category", bundle: nil)
        return myClassNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CategoryClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your `CategoryClass` code.

Comment: @ivarun i add Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of casting you need to change

```
var viewAll = [Int: UIView]()
```

to

```
var viewAll = [Int: CategoryClass]()
```

//

also change this

```
view.value.pcId.text = "TEST"
```

to

```
view.pcId.text = "TEST"
```